# Creating node-based photo galleries with prev/next links within each taxonomy (specific gallery)

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, nodes, media

I want to create a collection of photo galleries where each gallery has it's own main page with thumbnails, and clicking on each thumbnail takes you to the node for that thumbnail with the full-size version of the image as well as next/prev links to go to other node pages within that same gallery.  I don't want to use colorbox or lightbox, all node-based per image entry per gallery.

My current plan is to use taxonomy to specify the different galleries, use views to create the individual gallery homepage, and use a custom content type for each image's node.  I'm not sure how to get the next/previous links on the node page to only go to nodes within that specific gallery, and couldn't find a module upon my initial search.

I'll be using Drupal 7.  Are there any modules that would do this, or is there a better approach to achieving the result in a way other than what I'm planning?

Comment: Have you tried jcarousel? https://drupal.org/project/jcarousel

Comment: I've used jcarousel in the past but I was under the assumption that it only provides a carousel for items being scrolled within the same page/carousel.  Is there another way to use it?  The next/previous arrows are what I want, but once clicked they should load a new page, and each page should only have one image (that node).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like the Drupal 7 version of [Node Gallery](https://drupal.org/project/node_gallery) has everything I need. I installed it, and it took care of it without any custom configuration needed.